# Create multiple rows of data from one row of data and column value

Tags: r

I have a row of data that I would like to break out into 5 rows based on the value.

Attached is an image of what I'd like to achieve. I don't know where to start. The cost is divided evenly over the 7 days.

UPDATE:
I am now able to do this using the code below: but it is giving me an error:

1) it adds a last column called NA
2) it replaces all the values in for the first Var as NA

[Source Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0liavu9q7wrlbw/TEST1.csv?dl=0)

[image]

---

```
`df<-read.csv("C:\\TEST1.CSV")

df1<-df[FALSE,];

#For every week
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  #For all seven days
  for (j in 1:7){
    df1<-rbind(df1,df[i,]/7);
  }
}

df2<-data.frame(seq(as.Date("2011-05-02"), as.Date("2015-11-22"), by="days"),df1);

colnames(df2)<-colnames(df)

write.csv(df2, file = "C:TEST1RES.CSV")`
```

error observed: 
 in the output file, the first column of variable, i.e col 3 is always NA. How could this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple loop. by using `[FALSE,]` and `dim(df)[1]`, my script will adapt to bigger dimensions.

```
#Your original dataset
df<-matrix(c(5,3,1,6,4,2),2,3);

#New dataset
df1<-df[FALSE,];

#For every week
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
#For all seven days
  for (j in 1:7){
    df1<-rbind(df1,df[i,]/7);
  }
}

df2<-data.frame(seq(as.Date("2011-05-02"), as.Date("2011-05-15"), by="days"),df1);
colnames(df2)<-c("cal_day","cost a","cosy b","cost c")
```

If you have loaded your dataset, you should use:

```
colnames(df2)<-colnames(df)
```

Here is the result:

```
df2;
      cal_day    cost a    cost b    cost c
1  2015-05-02 0.7142857 0.1428571 0.5714286
2  2015-05-03 0.7142857 0.1428571 0.5714286
3  2015-05-04 0.7142857 0.1428571 0.5714286
4  2015-05-05 0.7142857 0.1428571 0.5714286
5  2015-05-06 0.7142857 0.1428571 0.5714286
6  2015-05-07 0.7142857 0.1428571 0.5714286
7  2015-05-08 0.7142857 0.1428571 0.5714286
8  2015-05-09 0.4285714 0.8571429 0.2857143
9  2015-05-10 0.4285714 0.8571429 0.2857143
10 2015-05-11 0.4285714 0.8571429 0.2857143
11 2015-05-12 0.4285714 0.8571429 0.2857143
12 2015-05-13 0.4285714 0.8571429 0.2857143
13 2015-05-14 0.4285714 0.8571429 0.2857143
14 2015-05-15 0.4285714 0.8571429 0.2857143
```

EDIT to answer the new error (read the comments)

It is impossible for me to solve your error without your dataset.
However, it appears that you have more weeks than what you expect. In order to have 1666 rows, you would need 238 weeks. The dates you input in `seq(...)` do not even give a result divisible by 7. They are therefore wrong. The last date in your original dataset must be later than the "2015-08-31" you put!

If you were to respect the 1666 days (7 times the number of weeks in your original dataset), that would be from "2011-05-02" to "2015-11-22".

`length(seq(as.Date("2011-05-02"), as.Date("2015-11-22"), by="days"));`

Originally you said you had 52 weeks. That would give 364 rows.

You are making a mistake in the code that we cannot fix because we cannot see the data. Just look at the original dataset and respect the same dates and it will work.

EDIT 2:

You forgot to get rid of the first column. Obviously, if you do not do it calculations on the dates are going to produce NAs.

Use this code instead:

```
df<-TEST1;
#Get rid of the first column
df1<-df[-1];


#New dataset
df2<-df1[FALSE,];


#For every week
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  #For all seven days
  for (j in 1:7){
    df2<-rbind(df2,df1[i,]/7);
  }
}

df3<-data.frame(seq(as.Date("2011-05-02"), as.Date("2011-05-15"), by="days"),df2);
colnames(df3)<-colnames(df);

head(df3);
```

Comment: that works perfectly!
also, can you point me towards a pdf that explains the df function? I'm a learner!

Comment: on this point of df matrices, would I have to add some lines of code so that when i read in my .csv file it is stored as a matrix?

Comment: df is just your data frame. `df[FALSE,]` gets rid of the raws and enable us to create an empty data frame that we then fill thanks to the loop.

Comment: I like this simple and efficient script to automatically solve the problem.

Comment: hello @Ouistiti i have tried this and came up with a problem which i don't quite know how to resolve. in the output, you'll see the number of days doesn't go above 15. i can show you the input file but dont know how to attach files in comments.


'df<-read.csv("C:.....test.csv")

df1<-df[FALSE,];

for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  #For all seven days
  for (j in 1:7){
    df1<-rbind(df1,df[i,]/7);
  }
}

df2<-data.frame(seq(as.Date("2011-05-02"), as.Date("2011-07-04"), by="days"),df1);
colnames(df2)<-c("CAL_WK","A","B","C", "D", "E", "F")
'

Comment: You just need to change the date 'as.Date("2011-05-15")' to the final date of your dataset.

Comment: @Ouistiti perfect, thats working - but, it's now giving me another problem. the output does not give the first column as a date - instead all the values in the first column appear as NA.
what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the exact code you are using? Everything is working on my end. Be sure that your number of dates is equal to the number of rows. To do that you can for example compare `dim(df1)[1]` and `length(seq(as.Date("choose-a-date"), as.Date("choose-a-date"), by="days"))`. If it different, it is not good.

Comment: @Ouistiti yes you are right - there is a difference in rows. this is the following error:

"There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> df1<-data.frame(seq(as.Date("2011-05-02"), as.Date("2015-08-31"), by="days"),df);
Error in data.frame(seq(as.Date("2011-05-02"), as.Date("2015-08-31"),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1583, 238"

Comment: `df<-read.csv("path.csv")

df1<-df[FALSE,];


#For every week
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  #For all seven days
  for (j in 1:7){
    df1<-rbind(df1,df[i,]/7);
  }
}
@Ouistiti

df1<-data.frame(seq(as.Date("2011-05-02"), as.Date("2015-08-31"), by="days"),df);

colnames(df1)<-colnames(df)`

Comment: Please use exactly the same code I used in my answer, just replace the first line with `df<-read.csv("path.csv")`. You are making a mistake as you using `df`  instead of `df1` in the `data.frame(...)` line. If that does not work, please put the code in an EDIT to your original post, not in the comments.

Comment: @Ouistiti hello my friend! I have updated the post with the code block and the observed error.

Comment: I edited my answer. You are making a mistake about the dates in the `seq(...)` object and you alone can see it.

Comment: @Ouistiti - yes, you are right :) - the seq dates were the problem. i've fixed that and the output is now giving me back dates, however, this time, its replacing my variable values ? have no idea why this could be! I've tried googling this but cannot find any answer that explains this. I have edited my question and included a link to dropbox with the source file that you can download and use.

Comment: I edited my answered. Everything is going to be alright now. Please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one solution you could try. Note that it might not work for others with similar problems because it assumes no dates are skipped.

**1. Your data.**

To demonstrate, I'll recreate a section of your data in R.

```
cost_a <- c(5, 6)
cost_b <- c(3, 4)
date <- c("2015-05-02", "2015-05-09")
df <- data.frame(date, cost_a, cost_b)
```

**2. Duplicating rows.**

You can use the rep function to replicate rows.

```
df.expanded <- df[rep(row.names(df), 7), 1:3]
```

The number 7 indicates how many duplicates you want (i.e. duplicate it 6 times). The 1:3 means the first to third columns. If you have 10 columns of costs, then it would be 1:11.

**3. Ordering the rows**

Using the default rep command does not order the rows the way you want, so you can quickly order them by date

```
df.sorted <- df.expanded[order(df.expanded$date),]
```

**4. Get the new values**

You can divide everything by 7 like this:

```
df.divided <- df.sorted/7
```

**5. Making the new dates.**

You can use the seq command to automatically create a list of dates.

```
date <- seq(as.Date("2015-05-02"), as.Date("2015-05-15"), by="days")
```

This assumes no days are skipped. Enter the first and last dates in the places where I've put the dates. You can also choose to make the list by other divisions besides days, if necessary.

**6. Merge the new dates with the divided values;**

```
df.divided$date <- date
```

Now use:

```
df.divided
```

To see if you get what you want

Comment: this looks like very good and just perfect for a learner. i'm going to run this and see what comes up! . super appreciate!

Comment: Nice way to replicate rows.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution using the *data.table* package:

```
library(data.table)
df <- setDT(df)[, .(dates = as.Date(date:(date+6), origin="1970-01-01"), 
                    cost_a = cost_a/7, 
                    cost_b = cost_b/7,
                    cost_c = cost_c/7), 
                by = date][, date:=NULL]
```

this gives:

```
> df
         dates    cost_a    cost_b    cost_c
 1: 2015-05-02 0.7142857 0.4285714 0.1428571
 2: 2015-05-03 0.7142857 0.4285714 0.1428571
 3: 2015-05-04 0.7142857 0.4285714 0.1428571
 4: 2015-05-05 0.7142857 0.4285714 0.1428571
 5: 2015-05-06 0.7142857 0.4285714 0.1428571
 6: 2015-05-07 0.7142857 0.4285714 0.1428571
 7: 2015-05-08 0.7142857 0.4285714 0.1428571
 8: 2015-05-09 0.8571429 0.5714286 0.2857143
 9: 2015-05-10 0.8571429 0.5714286 0.2857143
10: 2015-05-11 0.8571429 0.5714286 0.2857143
11: 2015-05-12 0.8571429 0.5714286 0.2857143
12: 2015-05-13 0.8571429 0.5714286 0.2857143
13: 2015-05-14 0.8571429 0.5714286 0.2857143
14: 2015-05-15 0.8571429 0.5714286 0.2857143
```

*Explanation:*

With `setDT(df)` you convert the dataframe to a datatable (which is an enhanced dataframe). With `by = date` you group by date. Supposing each date in the original dataframe is the starting date of a week, you create the complete week with `as.Date(date:(date+6), origin="1970-01-01")`.

---

Used data:

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("2015-05-02", "2015-05-09"),
                 cost_a = c(5, 6),
                 cost_b = c(3, 4),
                 cost_c = c(1, 2))
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
```

Comment: this is a terrific solution. however i am getting this error (listed below) - i have installed the package.
'
weeklydata = read.csv("filepath.csv")

library(data.table)

df <- setDT(df)[, .(CAL_WK = as.CAL_WK(CAL_WK:(CAL_WK+6), origin="2011-05-02"), 
                    a_d = A/7, 
                    b_d = B/7,
                    c_d = c/7, 
                    d_d = D/7, 
                    e_d = E/7),
                by = date][, date:=NULL]

Comment: You are using `as.CAL_WK` instead of `as.Date`. So: `as.CAL_WK(CAL_WK:(CAL_WK+6), origin="2011-05-02")` should be `as.Date(CAL_WK:(CAL_WK+6), origin="1970-01-01")`

Comment: @retroscience see my previous comment; hope this works